# What's a reasonably-secure, reasonably-portable way to allocate memory for private keys?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm looking for a "best practice" for allocating storage for 256-bit private keys.  I'm thinking at minimum, keys shouldn't be paged to disk, and there are maybe some other attack vectors to worry about (a la Hearbleed).  The solution must be portable to Linux and BSD.

Some thing I have looked at:

- TRESOR (not BSD-portable)
- Akamai's "secure heap"
- David Shaw's secmalloc
- Use mlock to forbid paging
- Just use malloc and don't worry.  A cursory reading suggests this may be what LibreSSL does.

Any recommendations?

Comment: By the way, what cipher are you using where 256-bit keys offer any security?

Comment: @R.. Modern symmetric ciphers (like AES)? Big sizes like 4096-bit are for asymmetric algorithms like RSA.

Comment: OP said "private keys" so I assumed public-key crypto, but perhaps the intent was just "keys that need to be kept private".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have special requirements, just using `malloc` is the sane approach. It has the advantage that valgrind and similar can catch usage errors, which are one of the main ways the type of vulnerabilities you may be worried about come into existence. As the OpenSSL fiasco showed us, trying to do something fancy and botching it is a major risk.

If you have more demanding requirements, it really depends a lot on your usage case. I'm going to assume your keys are transient, or else avoiding storing them on disk doesn't make a lot of sense. Here are my recommended mitigations for particular risks:

- Swapping to disk: If your system requires security against physical attacks, you should not have swap at all. Individually trying to protect specific data with `mlock` is something of a joke. Just turn swap off and install enough memory and it's a non-issue. `mlock` should be considered a realtime scheduling feature, not a security feature.
- Heartbleed-like issues, moderate defense: Allocating your memory via `mmap` with guard pages on both sides: first `mmap` 2 pages more than you need, all with `PROT_NONE`, then use `mprotect` to make all but the first and last page `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE`. Free it with `munmap` as soon as you're done with it.
- Heartbleed-like issues, strong defense: Fork a child process to do all the cryptography.